Why is the stem turning black on avocado tree
So this avocado tree is around almost 2 years old now I’ve cut it back a few times this is the first time this has happened but I’m worried about it spreading down the stem even more it did have root rot a while ago but changed the soil and using hydrogen peroxide also on it it showing really good growth but it still quickly turning black which I’m kinda concerned about I don’t know if I should worry or should try to do something about it but I have cut it down the black stem part a few times to try to prevent it from spreading but it isn’t working from what I can tell 

In my experience, when you prune an avocado it dies back to the base of the node.  I don't think you need to worry about it unless it spreads past the base of the node.

It's due to tissue necrosis due to water loss. It would have looked a bit appealing if you've immediately after cutting sprayed it with contact fungicide and coated end with wax.
